# How to document the Encryption or Hashing Method used in a Document?

Tags: encryption, hash

I am building a plain Text Editor that allows to encrypt, hash or sign passages. 
Since I want to allow for different Methods (symm/asymm, #Bits etc.), possibly even within the same document, the actually Method used must/should be documented in the same document, preferably directly before the encrypted passage.

I wonder if there is something like a standard plain text Prefix (or Suffix) for encrypted data/signatures similar to the protocol in a URL `http://` or `mail://` . 
The concatenated prefix and cipher (base64 encoded, also the encoding should go into the prefix) could look like this:

```
SHA1://XFe..ks== or 
RSA512://uD4lo...df5=
```

Comment: For hashes there is [RFC6920 - Naming Things with Hashes](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6920)

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [RFC 3369](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3369.txt), the Cryptographic Message Syntax standard.  It includes the relevant metadata which describes the information you're seeking.

Comment: Thanks, that seems already very detailed and I couldn't find an annotated version of this RFC. Even Wikipedia has only minimal Information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax How would this look like in practice?

Comment: The Windows CryptoAPI directly supports CMS, aka PKCS#7.    You could start there, if you're on that platform. Also, see RSA's documents on PKCS#7. They have better examples than the RFC.

Comment: Actually yes, I'm on Windows.NET using CMS and obtain a base64 cipher or hash, but I would like to adorn the result with a Prefix to tell readers which Encryption or hashing was used.

Comment: There are no standardized text prefixes that meet your requirement.  But then, you aren't exactly working with standardized files, so you can do what you need. Take a look at the ASCII-armored PGP file format.  The first line parsed starts with ----- BEGIN PGP MESSAGE ----- which is followed by a Version: line, then the base64 encoded details.  You could mimic this syntax, and include an Algorithm: line, for example.